# How to query Docker DNS from within a container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm using `docker-compose.yml` version 2. One of my containers doesn't see another one and I'm trying to debug this.

Previously, `docker-compose` relied on `links` mechanism for containers to interact with each other. It was implemented via dynamic modification of `/etc/hosts` file.

Starting from `docker-compose` version 2, `docker-compose` [relies upon Docker DNS mechanism](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2038). Now `/etc/hosts` is kept intact and containers query their internal Docker DNS to find each other.

I wonder, how do I query Docker DNS from within a container for debugging purposes? I want to make sure that it properly resolves the hostname of other containers in its network and that they are known by their aliases.

Comment: You can use a normal shell `docker exec -it container-name "bash"` inside the container to run commands like dig, just make sure dig (or whatever you want) is installed in the container.

Comment: @user3137702 Will `dig` or `host` see that they should query Docker DNS? I have 2 entries in my container's `/etc/resolv.conf`: `nameserver 69.20.0.164`
`nameserver 69.20.0.196`. Is one of them Docker DNS?

Comment: Dig (and everything else) use the built in resolver library, which uses resolv.conf.  It will not know anything specific about docker, just as the rest of the code running in the container doesn't.  With user defined networks, an IP (127.0.0.11) is added to the resolv.conf.  I believe the default networks use some kind of transparent NAT.

Comment: @user3137702 Your suggestion worked. Seems that first nameserver in `resolv.conf` is Docker DNS, while the second one is probably mapped to system DNS. First DNS successfully resolved all my links to IPs in docker network. Thanks!